# C# with AWS S3 access denied with transfer utility

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I've been trying for several hours to get this to work and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a bucket in US-West Oregon (us-west-2). I have an IAM user with full S3 access. I am attempting to store the contents of a string into a file on S3. Here is the code below:

```
using System.IO;
using Amazon;

namespace XXX.Util
{

    public static class S3
    {

        private static Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility transferUtility;

        public static void UploadFile(string bucket, string key, string contents)
        {    
            // user "publisher" credentials
            transferUtility = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility("{AccessID}", "{Secret}",RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

            using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(contents))
            {
                using (transferUtility)
                {
                    transferUtility.Upload(s, bucket, key);
                }
            }


        }
        public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

I invoke the method with:

```
S3.UploadFile("s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/{bucket-name}", guid.ToString(),contents);
```

The error message I get is:

> AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in
>   HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs, line 60

My S3 policy:

> {
>       "Version": "2012-10-17",
>       "Id": "Policy1516569218147",
>       "Statement": [
>           {
>               "Sid": "Stmt1516569211561",
>               "Effect": "Allow",
>               "Principal": {
>                   "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{iamID}:user/publisher"
>               },
>               "Action": "s3:*",
>               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket-name}"
>           }
>       ] }

Any ideas?

Comment: Delete the policy and try again. The S3 policy is not needed when signing requests. However, a broken S3 policy can deny signed requests. Your code looks fine and I do not see an obvious error. I think that your goal is to only allow uploads to "/user/publisher" but your "Principal" should be using AccountNumber and not iamID.

Comment: I do see one problem with your code. You are specifying a URL for the bucket name. It should just be the bucket name in your call to S3.UploadFile(). You are already setting the region via  Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility()

Comment: I believe you will need `"Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket-name}",  "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket-name}/*" ]` in your policy.  The second form refers to objects, the first one to the bucket itself.

Comment: John - your answer did it! I think using the bucket name instead of the full URL did the trick. Thanks, I was pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/access-denied-athena/):

> The S3 location matches the format s3://bucket/path. Don't include the
>   endpoint. For example, s3://us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/path
>   results in an "Access Denied" error.